# How to set the debug level for specific module in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

can anyone tell me how to set the debug level for specific module in fabric by changing the env variables in docker file? In the peer log ,we can see

> 2017-07-24 03:44:44.787 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 189 Module 'msp/identity' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
>
> 2017-07-24 03:44:44.787 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 18a Module 'msp' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
>
> 2017-07-24 03:44:44.787 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 18b Module 'configvalues/msp' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
>
> 2017-07-24 03:44:44.787 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 18c Module 'peer/gossip/mcs' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'
>
> 2017-07-24 03:44:44.787 UTC [flogging] setModuleLevel -> DEBU 18d Module 'gossip/state' logger enabled for log level 'WARNING'

I want some of them to be in debug mode, how to achieve that?
FYI, I have tried to set `GOSSIP_SERVICE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG` and `GRPC_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG` to make the module gossip/service and grpc in debug mode, but it doesn't work :( ...

Answer (score 5):

In order to change logging level for modules you need either to make changes in `core.yaml` file:

```
###############################################################################
#
#    LOGGING section
#
###############################################################################
logging:

    # Default logging levels are specified here.

    # Valid logging levels are case-insensitive strings chosen from

    #     CRITICAL | ERROR | WARNING | NOTICE | INFO | DEBUG

    # The overall default logging level can be specified in various ways,
    # listed below from strongest to weakest:
    #
    # 1. The --logging-level=<level> command line option overrides all other
    #    default specifications.
    #
    # 2. The environment variable CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL otherwise applies to
    #    all peer commands if defined as a non-empty string.
    #
    # 3. The value of peer that directly follows in this file. It can also
    #    be set via the environment variable CORE_LOGGING_PEER.
    #
    # If no overall default level is provided via any of the above methods,
    # the peer will default to INFO (the value of defaultLevel in
    # common/flogging/logging.go)

    # Default for all modules running within the scope of a peer.
    # Note: this value is only used when --logging-level or CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL
    #       are not set
    peer:       info

    # The overall default values mentioned above can be overridden for the
    # specific components listed in the override section below.

    # Override levels for various peer modules. These levels will be
    # applied once the peer has completely started. They are applied at this
    # time in order to be sure every logger has been registered with the
    # logging package.
    # Note: the modules listed below are the only acceptable modules at this
    #       time.
    cauthdsl:   warning
    gossip:     warning
    ledger:     info
    msp:        warning
    policies:   warning
    grpc:       error

    # Message format for the peer logs
    format: '%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}'
```

Or you can use `peer cli` tool to update logging level at runtime:

```
$ peer help logging

Log levels: getlevel|setlevel|revertlevels.

Usage:
  peer logging [command]

Available Commands:
  getlevel     Returns the logging level of the requested module logger.
  revertlevels Reverts the logging levels to the levels at the end of peer startup.
  setlevel     Sets the logging level for all modules that match the regular expression.

Global Flags:
      --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
      --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
  -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server

Use "peer logging [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

For example:

```
peer logging setlevel module_name debug
```

Will update logging level of `module_name` to debug.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer,  I think the second one is pretty helpful , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

core.yaml peer logging properties can be overridden by using docker environment variables, for example:

```
CORE_LOGGING_GOSSIP=debug
```

To put everything in debug mode use:

```
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
```

You can also list selective modules to put in debug mode:

```
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info:kvledger,statecouchdb,couchdb=debug
```

Note that starting in v1.4 there is a new environment variable that is common across peers and orderers:

```
FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info:kvledger,statecouchdb,couchdb=debug
```

Comment: I tried CORE_LOGGING_GOSSIP=error but it still shows all the debug messages. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variable `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC` to enable warning only.